# Invoke Lambda via function URL inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-networking

I am running an app that uses an API running inside a Lambda to serve HTTP requests. Currently requests come in via API gateway, API gateway invokes the Lambda, the Lambda connects to a database and gets the requested information and returns it. This is working well. The issue I have run into is that API Gateway has a request size of 10MB. Due to this I am looking to remove API gateway and use a reverse proxy running on a public EC2 instance.

The issue I am facing is trying to work out the best way to go about this. As I am no longer invoking the lambda via API gateway I figured that a Function URL would be the way to go.

The way I envision the setup would be:

Lambda - In VPC with a private subnet

Database - In VPC with a private subnet

EC2 Instance - In VPC with a public subnet

I have got this setup and I have connected an Internet Gateway to the public subnet and a NAT Gateway to the Private subnet.

The problem is that I cannot seem to call Lambda via the Function URL from the EC2 instance. I have also tried putting the Lambda in the Public Subnet, removing the NAT Gateway from the equation, but still no luck. Everytime the function URL just returns 301.

If I take the Lambda out of the VPC I can call it via the Function URL but it cannot connect to the DB (which makes sense).

I have checked the Security Groups on the Lambda and the VPC and cannot see any issues.

Here are some screenshots of the setup when the Lambda is in the public Subnet incase I have just completely missed something:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lambda functions have an even lower payload limit (6MB sync, 256KB async) than API Gateway (10MB). On the Lambda function URL invocation, your VPC networking setup is irrelevant to the actual invocation of the function, which happens via the Lambda control plane. The VPC networking will impact the invoked Lambda function's ability to reach public or private endpoints so you do need to pay attention to that.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod. If I am understanding you correctly, is it not possible to invoke a Lambda via a function URL if the Lambda is inside a VPC? On the limit front, while you are correct, it seems that those limits are measured differently.  E.G. the API gateway limit is the whole request size, whereas the Lambda limit it just the payload. However that is just based on my experience so far.

Comment: No, whether the Lambda function is connected to a VPC or not is irrelevant to the invocation of the Lambda function, either by API or function URL. The function will be invoked regardless of the VPC configuration.

Comment: Interesting, as that is the issue I am currently facing. While my Lambda is inside a VPC, the Function URL does not invoke my Lambda. It just returns a 301. But if I take it out of my VPC it starts to work

Comment: 301 is a redirection, not a failure. What is your client being redirected to? Also, you should see evidence of the function invocation in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Yes, 301 is a redirect, but the function is never invoked. If I hit the function URL using cURL -L I end up with Maximum (50) redirects followed. When removing the Lambda from the VPC I can see the function is invoked in the Cloudwatch logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252678/discussion-between-jarmod-and-hlt).